# "He was steeped in a to many people boring book?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, semantics

I am confused in the use and name of a class of adjectives similar to the following example:

> *He was steeped in a to many people boring book.*

Which has the meaning of "He was steeped in a book that is boring for many people." Is that grammatically and semantically correct?

Comment: Your punctuation there doesn't reflect the spoken intonation pattern for such phrases, which can be easier heard than read.

Comment: Do you mean “to many people”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That very particular sentence is very hard to read, so most people would say it is 'ungrammatical'.

However, the pattern that it seems to allude, a not uncommon one, while not formal (and so ungrammatical or rather unacceptable in a newspaper or formal speech) is to use an extended noun phrase syntactically like a preposed noun-attribute, modifying the following head noun.

To modify your example a tiny bit:

> He was reading a boring-to-too-many-people book.

This is very informal and would not make it past an editor or school teacher and called horribly ungrammatical. That said, it is a pattern that many native speakers use very informally (the way to say this is that the pattern is 'grammatical in a particular informal register').

The sentence would be translated to a more formal register as

> He was reading a book that was boring to too many people.

As with lots of informalities like this, if you are a non-native speaker, I would avoid using this kind of pattern because it will sound like a mistake if said with an accent. For a native speaker, it should probably be avoided in more than informal circumstances.

Comment: I’m not 100% positive that *hard-to-read signs* and such are so much
strictly ungrammatical as they are egregiously infelicitous. The fundamental underlying problem is that
modificands ***really*** want their heavier modifiers falling to their right not
their left so that you don’t have to keep so darned much pending and 
unfulfilled up in your head’s parsing stack till you finally get to the 
syntactic head you're looking for.  Better to let such
sleeping-in-the-doorway-of-the-room-you-need-to-get-into dogs lie.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, it can definitely lead to infelicity. Too long and it stretches processing abilities.

Comment: It's worth pointing out the OP didn't have *too* in their question.

Comment: @niamulbengali This answer was written before the OP changed things from 'too' to 'to'. The general principal of the informal pattern of using a full phrase as a preponed modifier still applies.

Comment: An alternative is << He was steeped in a – to many people boring – book. >> Using the parenthetical offsetting preserves meaning but probably reallocates emphasis. But both variants are clumsy, and I'm wondering why two disparate notions have to be paired in a single sentence here. // << He was steeped in a book. A book that to many people would be boring. >> (Fragments are not verboten per se.)

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but a solution to retain your structure is punctuation (and order adjustment):

> He was steeped in — to many people — a boring book.

This is the cleanest way, to me, to communicate your structure with more or less the same effect. You don't hear punctuation when speaking, so that's why this might look unusual at first. (Tone, speed, volume or pauses do this in speech.)

**Note:* I've used *em-dashes* which have certain rules around spacing depending on the writing style guide but I've used spaces on either side to create a clear, visual separation.*

### Explanation

"to many people" is an additional prepositional or adjectival phrase, depending on how you use it, to emphasise how boring the book is; it's not the main clause. The main clause is "*He was steeped in a boring book*". The rest is therefore extra information.

Due to its intended placement (extra information normally comes after knowing what we're talking about), it reads as an interruption. We call these structures *parenthetical*. The very structure of your writing is adding further emphasis which is a wonderful thing. Sometimes we use brackets or commas (as I have done in this answer) but hyphens allow for more immediacy.

Hyphenating visually separates both phrases, making the interruption clear, and creates a mental note for the reader that a deviation is occurring. The reader can save their reading rhythm for when they get past the hyphens. Commas and brackets have a softer effect and commas have more than one use that may distract from what you want.

### Placement of the 'a'

You could write this with the 'a' before the first hyphen but it risks a little more confusion. Putting it afterwards keeps the noun-phrase ("a boring book") together and allows people to comprehend what's happening in neater packets.

I'd be tempted to do that even if I had the 'a' before the first hyphen, because "boring book" ends up being awkward on its own IMO. But, repeating the 'a' would be ungrammatical, unless you're writing dialogue/colloquial speech (people don't always speak grammatically). So that's why I have the 'a' afterwards.